# Encryption using PHP and Decryption using C# & Vice Versa

Tags: c#, php

I am not getting the result of C# code in the PHP code.
The below PHP code and C# code is using to encrypt the text

**Variables For Reference:**

```
Test_String = "Testing";
Key = "11111111111111111111111111111111";
Iv = "11111111111111111111111111111111";
```

**PHP Code:**

I tried with the algorithm and cipher as AES-128-CBC for the same code

```
$Cipher_Text = openssl_encrypt($Test_String, "AES-256-CBC", $Key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $Iv);
$Enc_String =  implode(unpack("H*", $Cipher_Text));
$Enc_String = strtoupper($Enc_String);
```

**C# Code:**

```
byte[] toEncryptArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Test_String);
byte[] securityKeyArray = HexStringToByteArray(Key);
byte[] IVKey = HexStringToByteArray(Iv);
var objAESCryptoService = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
objAESCryptoService.Key = securityKeyArray;
objAESCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
objAESCryptoService.IV = IVKey;
objAESCryptoService.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
var objCrytpoTransform = objAESCryptoService.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] resultArray = objCrytpoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
objAESCryptoService.Clear();
string Result = ByteArrayToHexString(resultArray);
```

But I am getting output for both codes are different

```
B30977015031D190DE06DDFCDAFCF156 //PHP Result
79A300CB4BA568EF10B941113A4F887F //C# Result
055586200D7D200A8294FAC85265A8DD //PHP AES-128-CBC Result
```

Kindly highlight what I missed in the PHP code to achieve the C# result.
As I learned that the openssl_encrypt will do PKCS7 padding by default, but the expected result is not getting as a result of PHP code.

Your suggestion will be helpful to understand this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: On the PHP part, better use `hex2bin()` in your `Iv`, I think it will return some warning, I can't remember

Comment: I found you a solution here: https://gist.github.com/Oranzh/2520823f9d1cea603e60b8e8f3fe1d36